# httpd : Different website depending on remote ip

Tags: httpd

Is it possible to serve 2 differents website with the same domain for request comming for 2 ip range.

For example I want that mydomain.com serves website A and for ip comming from Europe serves website B.

Is that possible with apache 2.2 ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be implemented with iptables redirecting.

1) I assume that first site listens to `*:80`, second site listens to `localhost:81` (or something like this)

2) range of ips that should see second site can be redirected to localhost:81.

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 81 -m comment --comment 'redirect range of ips to second site'`

This means: route (-j REDIRECT) all tcp connections to 80 port (-p tcp --dport 80) from network 192.168.1.0/24 (-s 192.168.1.0/24) to the 81 port of the localhost

You can also try to use `-m iprage --src-range 1.2.3.4-2.3.4.5` or few entries of the `-s ip/mask` syntax to achieve effect you want.

Comment: Whilst this works, trying to work out the IP addresses and ranges for a continent would be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible, it is actually quite common even. And there are several ways to do this, depending on your OS, what webserver you use etc...

If you are using apache you can for example use mod_geoip2. More information you can find here:
http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/mod_geoip2